# Продажа предметов в игре

Tags: python, pygame

я сделал продажу предметов в игре , но после продажи предмет нельзя заново получить(добыть), то есть мы продаем 7 рыбок получаем например 20 монет.

Но после даже если получать рыбу ее кол-во будет равняться 0, ведь я продал рыбу и обнулил ее счетчик.

Пробовал минусовать количество предметов пока оно не будет равно нулю, но обнуление шло дальше.

Вот примерный код:

```
class player(object):
  def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.fish = 10
  def sell:
    score = fish * 10
    if score >= 1:
      fish = 0
    if keys(pygame.K_a):
      x = random.randint(1,10)
      if x == 5:
        fish += 1
```

Comment: Если будут вопросы, задавайте ... я дополню код если нужно

Comment: Надо на листочке расписать что происходит в программе с разными предметами, персонажами, какие действия совершаются и что в результате получается, иначе все запутывается при написании кода

Comment: все это расписано, просто при продаже рыбы ее больше невозможно получить тоесть: Я выловил 10 рыбок и продал их, счетчик рыб обнулился, а деньги прибавились(В программе типо если рыбок больше 1, я меняю их на 10 монет каждую , а рыбок становится 0) и больше я получить не могу, программа считатет , что рыбок 0 и все их нельзя получить.

Comment: Значит надо ещё наловить. Где это в программе?

Comment: последняя строка примерно отражает это,  тоесть при нажатии кнопки в определенной области начинается ловля и рыбка ловится. Но как только продаю и пытаюсь вновь наловить ничего не выходит.

Comment: Проблему решил сам,пришлось немного переписать код и добавить пару данных. По итогу создал класс и переписал значения рыбок туда и уже от него исходило исчисление.